# Using transformer with secondary shorted to primary

Tags: power, transformer

I acquired a broken piece of vintage gear in which the transformer has one primary and many secondaries.  Examining the crispy remains of the transformer, I found that one of the secondaries shorted to the primary.  All the other secondaries appear to remain isolated from everything else.  The transformer isn't easily replaced, and with all the secondaries, I'm reluctant to try to rewind it.  I'm considering adding an additional transformer to replace the one damaged secondary--my question is would I be able to safely get away with using the damaged transformer leaving the one shorted secondary out of circuit?

Comment: Are you sure that it is a fault that one secondary is shorted to the primary? In an [autotransformer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autotransformer) this is intended.

Comment: Yes, it's definitely a fault and not intended.

Answer (score 2):

Since one winding has failed then the others may not be far away, so in terms of safety you should replace it.

Comment: Agreed.  While some people go nuts over "all original" gear, there's little point in keeping a part that's only going to blow up again soon and possibly take some other parts with it.  Plus, some of those vintage designs are downright scary and *should* be modified for the sake of user safety alone!

Comment: I have had a transformer professionally rewound, to a specification derived from the original transformer. It was a reasonably priced option for an otherwise unattainable component on a 50 year old piece of equipment, but it's not easy to find a company to do it.